# Evaluating every conditional statement on an if... else if... block

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, performance, if-statement, switch-statement

Does Objective-C evaluate every statement on an `if... else if...` block or does it evaluate each as it comes to them and then skip the remaining evaluations if a true condition has been found?

This is more of a pragmatic question related to performance than anything else.

And yes I do know that the content of the if block itself isn't executed, but I am referring to the actual statements that get evaluated.

Example

```
if ([condition A] == test) {
  // Do something
} else if ([condition B] == test) {
  // Do something    
} else if ([condition C] == test) {
  // Do something    
} else {
  // Do something because all other tests failed
}
```

So... if condition A is true, do conditions B and C get evaluated anyway?

If they do, then does using a switch statement perform the same way or does a switch only test each condition as it comes to it and then exits the evaluation because of the break?

My understanding is that on an `if... else if...` block, every condition is evaluated and therefore using a switch or nested if's (ugh - don't relish the thought there) might be faster on big evaluation operations on a lot of data (hundreds of thousands of items being checked against potentially a hundred statements).

Just curious :-)

Comment: The better question is, "Does C ...?" as the basic flow control is inherited from C. Objective-C is a superset of C.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, if condition A is met, B and C are not evaluated. Indeed, they are part of the else-clauses that won't get executed then anyway.

Just a side note: `if (condA || condB)` or if (condA && condB) also evaluates lazily, i.e. in the first case condB is only evaluated if condA is false, in the second case when condA is true.

Comment: Eiko - the side note could actually come in handy and was for me the next natural extension to the question... Great to know. Thanks.

Comment: The computer sciency term is 'short-circuit evaluation'. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit_evaluation

Comment: @Eiko, your Side Note is important for me. Do you have an apple developer link to show me where you get this info from apple ? I mean I have a long if statement and for speed reasons I want to be sure it will only check second if first is true and only third if first and second are true, and so on. And I would like to read more on how IF is treated in objective-C. Thx

Comment: @HpTerm This is not specific to ObjC - it's a standard feature of C. Maybe start with the wikipedia link from Andrew.

Answer (score 4):

It only evaluates them as it comes to them. An `if ... else if` block is equivalent to `if.. else {if...}`. It behaves the same way as nested ifs, it's just formatted nicely and omits some braces.

Answer (score 2):

Outside of the []'s objective-c behaves in exactly the same way that C does.

For `if() ... else if() ... else ...` chains that means each expression is evaluated until one evaluates to true and the block is entered.  Basically

```
if (a) {
    ...
} else if (b) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

is interpreted as

```
if (a) {
    ...
} else {
    if (b) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Olliej - thanks for the feedback. This is all good news for my code :-)